# HDMI > eDP 1.2 converter

Tags: voltage, usb, converter, laptop, hdmi

I have a spare 15.6 laptop screen and want to turn it into a small portable monitor. By portable I mean that it should not require to be plugged into an electric socket. The screen itself only needs 3.3v, which seems to be little enough for an HDMI (or USB) port to put out.

My research has not been successful yet. There are so called lcd driver board controllers available, but they all need 12v of external power. That's pretty much it for what I could find.

Is it possible to send signal from HDMI to this screen and power it from HDMI itself or USB? Maybe there's someone that could share some insights on this topic?

The screen model is PANDA LM156LF5L06, 1920*1080.

Thank you

Comment: HDMI doesn't really give out much current. Normally an unpowered device is allowed to draw 50mA and powered device 10mA.

Comment: It's not the voltage, it's the current that will be the issue. Even if you could power the logic part of the converter there's no way will you be able to power the LED backlight from an HDMI port.

Comment: Would USB/HDMI+USB power the LED backlight?

Comment: @IvanSchemm You need the display data sheet to read how many supply voltages it requires and how much current it requires from each supply. We cannot know if the power the display requires is within limits of USB or not. And what kind of USB you mean.

Comment: @Justme laptop screen datasheets turned out to be tricky to obtain. 
But I've managed to find [one describing a screen similar to mine](https://www.displaytechnology.co.uk/assets/product_files/hd-10-094.pdf). 
It seems to need 3.3V 430mA (1.4W) for converter part and 12V 470mA (5.6W) for backlight. These are "typical" consumption values but there is also a "minimum" column so I assume it could live on slightly less power than that. 
The kind of USB I mean is non-PD USB-C 3.2 gen 1. It should be able to output 3A 5V (15W) judging by one Tom's Hardware article. Or multiple USBs combined.